# How to migrate Ionic 4.2.0 to latest version?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

My Ionic information is -

[image]

I want to upgrade it to latest veriosn i.e 4.7.0, How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the **[release notes](https://ionicframework.com/docs/release-notes)** to see how to install this (and every) version of Ionic 4.

> With this version comes support for **Angular 8!** Follow the below steps
>   to update.
>
> 1) Update `@ionic/angular` and `@ionic/angular-toolkit` to the latest
>   releases:
>
> ```
> npm install @ionic/angular@4.7.0 
> npm install @ionic/angular-toolkit@2.0.0 -D
> ```
>
> 2) Update `@angular/core` and `@angular/cli`:
>
> ```
> npx ng update @angular/core @angular/cli
> ```
>
> 3) Update @angular-devkit dependencies:
>
> ```
> npm i @angular-devkit/architect@latest @angular-devkit/build-angular@latest @angular-devkit/core@latest @angular-devkit/schematics@latest
> ```
>
> View our **[Angular 8 Update Guide](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QOpQeDifPSg6F9WycDLcbQnpqjN96ew-Ap0_CB7CcCQ/edit)** for tips on potential issues!

Once that's ready, you can finally update the Ionic version:

```
npm install @ionic/angular@4.7.0 --save-exact
```

Answer (score 0):

using specific version can achive

**globally**

```
npm install -g ionic@4.7.0
```

**locally**

```
 npm install ionic@4.7.0
```